# Objective c subview in UITableViewCell background color on select

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, addsubview

Hi all im fairly new to ios so still have a lot to learn, im adding a subview with dynamic background color from a webservice to a table cell but on select the subviews background color is changing to the table cells selected state color, I know why its doing this as it changes all the sub views background color's within a view, I just cant seem to work out how to stop it from changing the subview background color as well, i want it to remain as the dynamic color chosen?

```
array = [colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UIView *colorBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,20,20)];
        [colorBox setTag:1];            
        [cell.contentView addSubview:colorBox];
    }

 UIView *box = [cell viewWithTag:1];
 box.backgroundColor = [self colorForBox:array.color];

 return cell;
```

and then getting the colors

```
- (UIColor *)colorForTransport:(NSString*)Line {

if([Line isEqualToString:@"Brown"])
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.682 green:0.38 blue:0.094 alpha:1];

else if([Line isEqualToString:@"Red"])
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.894 green:0.122 blue:0.122 alpha:1];

else
    return DefaultBackgroundColor;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you trying to stop?

Answer (score 0):

You might try altering the selectedBackgroundView subview of the tablecellview to get the colour change you are looking for.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/selectedBackgroundView for more info on that property

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a plain-style table, then you'll need to alloc-init a new UIView having your desired background colour and then assign it to selectedBackgroundView.

Or something like,

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new subclass which inherits from UIView.
Then override setBackgroundColor to do nothing.
And add your own method which will set background color. In that way system will not be able to override your background color and you can set any color using your new method :)

```
-(void) setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    //do nothing
}

//System do not know this method :)
-(void) mySetBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell changes the backgroundColor of all subviews on selection for some reason.

This might help:

[DVColorLockView](https://github.com/DylanVann/DVColorLockView)